# PHP Lua Extension

Tags: php, lua, wamp, pecl

I am looking into using Lua with PHP, but I can't figure out how to set it up to be a PHP extension (DLL). I can't find ANY documentation on this, so does anyone have any experience with this/PECL? Here is the link: http://pecl.php.net/package/lua

I see that MediaWiki has implemented this, and I was trying to figure it out on my website, but I've been stumped for about a week now.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: In [the docs](http://www.laruence.com/lua/), you have **Just define the CFLAGS = -I/path/to/lua/ -L/path/to/lua -llua** for Win32.

Comment: http://www.php.net/install.pecl.windows - Easier without Windows though, where you can just do `pecl install lua`

Comment: @DreamEater How do I do that?